# Unable to mount Windows partition - fast boot is already off - still get the problem

Tags: dual-boot, mount, windows-8

i have installed windows 8.1 and ubuntu on my new computer, and get the following error when i try to mount the device. I already googled and turned all the hibernation / fastboot options off, but i still have this problem. The option secure boot is disabled in the UEFI-BIOS aswell. Does anyone have an idea, what might cause the problem? And is there a chance to overwrite the Ubuntu error and mount the device -w to do some testing?

Thank you,

here's the error-message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/simon/9A3E3EEF3E3EC453: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/simon/9A3E3EEF3E3EC453"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and found the solution [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/delete-hiberfilsys-by-disabling-windows-hibernate-function/).

> The only surefire method of disabling Hibernate, and thus removing hiberfil.sys, on Windows Vista and Windows 7, is through the command prompt and the following steps:
>
> 1. Open a command prompt with administrative privileges.
> 2. Enter "powercfg.exe -h off" (see Figure D).
> 3. Exit the command prompt.

I had fast boot and hibernate unchecked but apparently that hiberfil.sys was still in my file system! Open a command prompt within Windows in administrator mode and run "powercfg.exe -h off". This should delete that file if you have it and hopefully solve the issue.

Comment: please [Provide context for links](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) _"...Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."_

Answer (score 0):

When shutting down your Windows run this on CMD `shutdown -s -t 0` to shut your Windows down it make Windows fully shutted down and release it's handle from it's partition

after that,mount your Windows partition on Ubuntu normally or by editting **fstab**

Answer (score -1):

After looking at your error log its clear that your pc is on Fast startup .In Windows 8 and 8.1, there is a function known as hybrid shutdown that  is enabled by default to make booting faster . Just because of this it leaves the filesystem on hibernate and it cant shutdown properly and this kind of error prompts.

To resolve this issue boot into windows and do the following -

1. Open the `Control Panel` then direct to `Hardware and sound`and `click on Power Options`
2. Click on `Choose what the power buttons do`
3. Click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable`
4. Under Shutdown settings, check the `Turn off fast startup box`, and click `Save changes button`.

restart your pc and see if it works. Information gathered from http://www.techulator.com/resources/5201-How-enable-or-disable-Hybrid-Boot-Windows.aspx

If still that partition is not mounting install Gparted then restart and check  and paste the screenshort of it here.

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this already after i googled for the problem. It still does not work at all. 

Here's my gparted screenshot: 
https://db.tt/dmwurzno - i guess i have not enough reputation to post images.

Comment: Adding an answer directly contradicting what the asker has already done suggests you think they're of inadequate skill to perform the task, and recognize they did it.